# SQL CASE INT Conversion

Tags: sql

I am trying to use `CASE` to group table contents that include characters and `NULL` and Blank entries using the following:

```
SELECT  COUNT(*) AS Clients,
   CASE WHEN t.Diagnosedin = 'Unknown' OR t.Diagnosedin ='' THEN 'Unknown' 
   ELSE CASE WHEN CAST((CAST(DATENAME(Year,GETDATE()) AS INT)- t.Diagnosedin)AS varchar(5)) =1 THEN 1
   ELSE CASE WHEN CAST((CAST(DATENAME(Year,GETDATE()) AS INT)- t.Diagnosedin)AS varchar(5)) <=2 THEN 2
   ELSE CASE WHEN CAST((CAST(DATENAME(Year,GETDATE()) AS INT)- t.Diagnosedin)AS varchar(5)) <=5 THEN 5
   ELSE CASE WHEN CAST((CAST(DATENAME(Year,GETDATE()) AS INT)- t.Diagnosedin)AS varchar(5)) <=10 THEN 10 
   ELSE CASE WHEN CAST((CAST(DATENAME(Year,GETDATE()) AS INT)- t.Diagnosedin)AS varchar(5))>=10 THEN '+10 '
   END
   END
   END
   END
   END
   END AS Years
```

I get the following error: `Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Unknown' to data type int.`, I am using MS SQL 2008.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What's happening is that you're mixing literals of different datatypes in the column `Years`. (i.e. int `5` and varchar `Unknown` will be in the same resultset). You need to code those literal values as the same datatype.

Try this:

- cast your hardcoded integers to strings/varchar. I've used the [`STR()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189527.aspx) function, and used the `LRTIM()` to ensure that the leading spaces aren't kept.
- use the same `CASE`

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS Clients,
   CASE WHEN t.Diagnosedin = 'Unknown' OR t.Diagnosedin ='' THEN 'Unknown' 
    WHEN CAST((CAST(DATENAME(Year,GETDATE()) AS INT)- t.Diagnosedin)AS varchar(5)) =1 THEN LTRIM(STR(1))
    WHEN CAST((CAST(DATENAME(Year,GETDATE()) AS INT)- t.Diagnosedin)AS varchar(5)) <=2 THEN LTRIM(STR(2))
    WHEN CAST((CAST(DATENAME(Year,GETDATE()) AS INT)- t.Diagnosedin)AS varchar(5)) <=5 THEN LTRIM(STR(5))
    WHEN CAST((CAST(DATENAME(Year,GETDATE()) AS INT)- t.Diagnosedin)AS varchar(5)) <=10 THEN LTRIM(STR(10)) 
    WHEN CAST((CAST(DATENAME(Year,GETDATE()) AS INT)- t.Diagnosedin)AS varchar(5))>=10 THEN '+10 '
END AS Years
```

Comment: Sounds like you've got two rows in your table where `Diagnosedin` has the value blank or `Unknown` then. You must likely need a GROUP BY clause to help there.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is there in front of you. You can only return one data type in a column. Your first WHEN statement establishes Unknown (string) as a value. Subsequent statements deliver integer values. The db engine says I got an integer and I need to stick a string in it and that won't fit.

Options are to add a cast to all the numeric operations to convert them to varchar(n) {as p.campbell just submitted} or to change your Unknown value to something like NULL or an obviously not valid sentinel value like -1.